# No funciona assoc en mi funcion (Clojure)

Tags: lista, vectores, clojure

Tengo que realizar una función que invierta los elementos de un vector que contiene vectores, y estos también tengo que invertirlos.
Estuve realizando pruebas y encontré la función assoc que modifica los elementos de un vector, pero por alguna razón no funciona

```
(defn invertir[lista]
    (def newlist [1 1 1 1])
    (loop [x (- (count lista) 1)]
      (when (> x -1)
        (do
          (def vectemp (nth lista x))
          (def atemp (nth vectemp 0))
          (def btemp (nth vectemp 1))
          (def vecimp [btemp, atemp])
          (assoc newlist (- (count lista) x 1) vecimp)
        )
        (recur (dec x))
      )
    )
    (print newlist)
  nil
)
;;; Test
(invertir '([1 a][2 a][1 b][2 b]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues a mí se me ocurre esto.
Puedes probar el código aquí: [Clojure online](https://tryclojure.org/)

```
(def lista [[1 "a"][2 "a"][1 "b"][2 "b"]])

(defn invertir-elementos [lista]
  (->> (reverse lista)
       (mapv (fn [elemento] (vec (reverse elemento))))))

(invertir-elementos lista)

;; [["b" 2] ["b" 1] ["a" 2] ["a" 1]]
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].